How to make a window/frame/control draggable?
How can I make the wxGrid instance draggable? That is the wxGrid is embedded on the main wxFrame. By default one can move the whole app window by clicking on the title bar and just dragg. How to make the whole app window be movable/draggable that is also when clicked/grabbed inside the inner wxGrid object?
Here is the illustration:
And the code:
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>

class ImageBgFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    ImageBgFrame(wxFrame* frame, const wxString& title);

private:

    void OnImagePanelPaint(wxPaintEvent&);
    void OnExit(wxCommandEvent&);
    void CreateScaledBg();

    wxImageHandler* m_pngLoader;
    wxPanel* m_imagePanel;
    wxImage m_image;
    wxBitmap m_BgBitmap;
    wxGrid* m_grid;

};

ImageBgFrame::ImageBgFrame(wxFrame* frame, const wxString& title)
    :wxFrame(frame, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    m_pngLoader = new wxPNGHandler();
    wxImage::AddHandler(m_pngLoader);

    m_grid = new wxGrid( this, -1, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(400, 300) );
    m_grid->CreateGrid(3, 8);
    m_grid->SetCellValue(0, 0, "823");
    m_grid->SetColFormatFloat(1);
    m_grid->SetColFormatFloat(2);

    // Try to load the image.
    m_image = wxImage("D:\\Pobrane_2\\armor_info3.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    if (!m_image.IsOk())
    {
        return;
    }

    // Create the controls.
    m_imagePanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    CreateScaledBg();
    
    Layout();

    // Bind Event Handlers
    m_imagePanel->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &ImageBgFrame::OnImagePanelPaint, this);
}

void ImageBgFrame::OnImagePanelPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
{
    if (m_imagePanel->GetSize() != m_BgBitmap.GetSize())
    {
        CreateScaledBg();
    }
}

void ImageBgFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent&)
{
    Close();
}

void ImageBgFrame::CreateScaledBg()
{
    wxSize sz = m_imagePanel->GetSize();
    m_BgBitmap = wxBitmap(m_image.Scale(sz.GetWidth(), sz.GetHeight(),
        wxIMAGE_QUALITY_NORMAL));
}


class ImageBgApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit()
    {
        ImageBgFrame* frame = new ImageBgFrame(NULL, "Image BG");
        frame->SetTransparent(150);
        frame->Show();
        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(ImageBgApp);


Looks like to make the wxGrid draggable, allowing the entire window (wxFrame) to be moved when clicking and dragging inside the wxGrid, you'll need to handle mouse events directly on the wxGrid widget

@Dario101, do you need to drag the actual wxGrid inside the wxPanel/wxWidndow? Or you want to drag the window when you click and drag the wxGrid object? Please clarify.

@Igor the second one - I'd like click and drag the wxGrid object to move the whole app window (NOT the grind inside the window!).

@Dario101, ypu should connect the mouse events to the https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_grid.html#afea39b9fe78fb9c0e52b0f60423351f7 object. In the click, set  the flag and call CaptureMouse(). In the release drop the flag and call ReleaseCapture(). Check the docs here - https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_window.html#a5c72c6260a73ef77bb0b1f7ec85fcfef

You will have to capture mouse events (button down, move, release, capture loss) on all grid windows, i.e. wxGrid::GetGridWindow(), GetGridRowLabelWindow(), GetGridColLabelWindow() and GetGridCornerLabelWindow() and move the window yourself accordingly.
Under Windows (only) a simpler to make the whole window draggable is by returning HTCAPTION from WM_NCHITTEST handler, but this will almost surely prevent the user from using wxGrid normally.
